# How to find which table column corresponds to a constraint in a Firebird database?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I have a legacy Firebird (Version 2.5.2) database and am using FlameRobin (Version 0.0.2.1851) to inspect it.

I have run the following query on the RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS table to search for the constraint named 'INTEG_172':

```
SELECT *
FROM RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS a
WHERE RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'INTEG_172'
```

The query returns the RDB$RELATION_NAME column as being 'Meeting' which I am assuming is the Meeting table. But my question now is: how do I find out which column in the Meeting table this constraint belongs to?

Comment: Do you want a query, or do you want to know how to find this in Flamerobin?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Either a query or in Flamerobin would be suitable.

Comment: The quick solution is to open the properties of the table in flamerobin, tab Constraints. It will show the name and columns. I had expected the answer by Ed Mendez to solve your problem as well. I will see if I can come up with a query later today.

Comment: @praj I found this post very helpful in finding constraints across the whole database: https://www.firebirdnews.org/listing-the-foreign-keys-in-a-firebird-database/#comment-21541

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I initially thought it was not possible to infer the column name of some of the constraints, but it turns out the `NOT NULL` constraints are actually implemented as `CHECK` constraints.

I have expanded the query by Ed Mendez in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25252067/466862) to also include check constraints which should give you all constraints and the tables and columns they use (with the exception of the target table+columns of a foreign key as I was too lazy to include `RDB$REF_CONSTRAINTS`):

```sql
SELECT RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME, RDB$CONSTRAINT_TYPE, 
       RDB$RELATION_NAME, RDB$FIELD_NAME
FROM (
    SELECT REL_CONS.RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME, REL_CONS.RDB$CONSTRAINT_TYPE, 
           REL_CONS.RDB$RELATION_NAME, ISEG.RDB$FIELD_NAME 
    FROM RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS REL_CONS
    INNER JOIN RDB$INDEX_SEGMENTS ISEG
        ON ISEG.RDB$INDEX_NAME = REL_CONS.RDB$INDEX_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT REL_CONS.RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME, REL_CONS.RDB$CONSTRAINT_TYPE, 
           REL_CONS.RDB$RELATION_NAME, CH_CONS.RDB$TRIGGER_NAME 
    FROM RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS REL_CONS
    INNER JOIN RDB$CHECK_CONSTRAINTS CH_CONS
        ON CH_CONS.RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME = REL_CONS.RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME
) a
WHERE a.RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'INTEG_172'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is what you are looking for...

```sql
SELECT RDB$INDEX_SEGMENTS.RDB$FIELD_NAME 
FROM   RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS
INNER JOIN RDB$INDEX_SEGMENTS 
    on ( RDB$INDEX_SEGMENTS.RDB$INDEX_NAME = RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS.RDB$INDEX_NAME )
WHERE RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS.RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'INTEG_172'
```

Comment: The query returned no data. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @prajna This query works on my Firebird 2.5.3. Try dropping the where and include `RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS.RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME` in the select. The other possibility is that this is a `NOT NULL` constraint, for some reason those aren't directly associated with a column.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do:

show table meeting; (via sql)

and read the constraint definition

Comment: Thanks but the sql failed to run and got the following: Error: *** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Statement::Prepare( show table Meeting )
Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed

Comment: this was to be run using the sql tool that is part of the firebird installation or 3-rd party tool, not via ibpp